# create new file using python cgi server side script

Tags: python, filesystems, cgi, server-side

I have tried to create new text file using pure python in terminal (ubuntu) , it worked well and it created new file but when I try the same code in server side with cgi , it does not creates new file .

Here is sample code i have tried

```
print "Content-type: text/html"
fo = open("foo.txt", "a")
fo.write( "Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!\n");
fo.close()
```

Comment: where i can get python error logs in ubuntu apache ????

Comment: Where are you trying to create this file? Maybe you're searching for it in a wrong directory?

Comment: i'm creating in my root folder (localhost) but i didn't found file which is generated by python code